# How to add restirction that only Azure CDN can access the static website in storage accounts container. No direct access of static website blob URL

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-website-hosting

I have created a blob container and made it a static website hosting, where inside the $web folder I have put all the build files of my react application. Please refer to the below image

[image]

And I have enabled the CDN for the storage account. Add the below rules

[image]

Azure CDN URL - https://ghcrablobcdn.azureedge.net

Static Website URL - https://ghcrablobcdn.z13.web.core.windows.net/

Now I want to make that only Azure CDN can access the static website URL, Direct access to the Static Website URL has to be prohibited or it shows 404, like that.

How can I add this restriction?

Do I have to add any network restrictions or like that?

your help or solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@gunnarpeipman](https://gunnarpeipman.com/access-restricted-blob-storage-from-azure-cdn/) for the clear steps.

> Do I have to add any network restrictions or like that?

Yes, we need to configure few options in `Storage Account` =>`Networking` Section.

Select the Public network option as shown below and `Add new virtual network`

[image]

[image]

***OR***

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-sas-storage-support#setting-up-azure-cdn-to-work-with-storage-sas), we can configure our storage account with `SAS - Shared access signature` to restrict the access.

[image]

Now configure the CDN to use the generated `SAS` token.

Navigate to the `CDN` => `Endpoint` => `Origin`

[image]